# Web Site Administration Tool:Unable to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, website-admin-tool

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC3 application using,

1. MS SQL Server Pro 2008
2. MS VS 2010 pro
3. Entity FrameWork as model class.

When i start ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool by clicking ASP.NET Configuration from solution explorer, in Security tab it shows an error:

**Unable to connect to SQL Server database.**

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config has a connection string as,

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data   source=.\MSSQLSERVER;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I opened the 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe
and configure the database default named 'aspnetdb'. But situation is not being improved. So, would you please help me to solve it. 
Thank you.

Comment: is your MSSQLSERVER service started? Check to see if default port 1433 is open to connect with ms sql management tool. Usually that service starts late than iis

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the database server that **Visual Studio** attempts to use?

It should match the one specified in your **web.config** file.

To check to go: **Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Design-time Validation Database.**

You can then change the SQL Server instance which is used.

Comment: yea, the default instance was SQLEXPRESS. i changed it to MSSQLSERVER.
but, nothing happened.

Comment: You mention that the connection string is in machine.config, does your application have its own web.config file? Also have you checked that the MS SQL service is running?